# curb gem on Mac Lion

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-lion, curb

I'm trying to install the curb gem in my Mac OSX Lion. I tried all solutions cited here already, like [Having Issues with Curb gem on Mac Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350141/having-issues-with-curb-gem-on-mac-snow-leopard)

my environment ruby 1.9.2 (rvm), mac OSX Lion, Xcode installed, lib curl (through  sudo port install curl +universal command) installed.

the results from bundle install and my lib curl path is in this gist:

https://gist.github.com/1652989

based on my lib curl installation (as well on gist) I did try as well this compile command:

```
rake install EXTCONF_OPTS='--with-curl-dir=/opt/local/include/curl --prefix=/opt/local'
```

which failed. any idea?

Comment: Can't replicate this with the current github master (which is 0.8.0 +). `extconf.rb` uses `curl-config`. Is macports in your path before `/usr/bin` (lion ships with curl)? As the `rake` message says, we'd need the `mkmf.log` lines relevant to `curlinfo_redirect_time`. failing ...

Comment: i did update my gist with mkmf.log output. it says that  execvp: No such file or directory..

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old and might not pertain to Mac Lion specifically.

If you are using ruby, try

```
gem install curb --platform=ruby
```